# Import Numpy in Python WebJob on Azure

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, numpy, azure-webjobs

How do I add Numpy (and other requirements) to a Python WebJob on Microsoft Azure?

I have deployed a Python WebJob on Azure, and was able to import packages by copying them manually from my local system to a folder `site-packages` and calling `sys.path.append('site-packages')`, [as explained in this post](http://nicholasjackson.github.io/azure/python/python-packages-and-azure-webjobs/). This works fine for some packages, but not for numpy.

When trying to import numpy, I get this error:

`File "site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
     from . import multiarray
ImportError: cannot import name 'multiarray'`

I have tried using the numpy folder from my Mac running python 3.5, and from a Windows PC running python 3.4. The Azure WebJob is running python 3.4.

Ideally I would like to put a `requirements.txt` somewhere, but this doesn't seem to work with Azure WebJobs.

Comment: See if this answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23831479/use-numpy-scipy-in-azure-web-role

Comment: These solutions all use a `requirements.txt`, which apparently works with Azure Web Apps, and Web Roles, but not with WebJobs.

Comment: Please try to follow the section `Troubleshooting: Package Installation ` of https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-python-create-deploy-flask-app/#troubleshooting---package-installation to do it.

Comment: How can I call pip from a WebJob?

Comment: That link that you said works fine for some packages is now down. How did you get it to work? I can't get mine to read any packages.

Comment: I have 3 powershell scripts that run at the start of the webjob: `PrepPython.ps1`, `PipInstaller.ps1` and `LaunchWorker.ps1`. The scripts and their order are defined in `ServiceDefinition.csdef`. This is the code of `PipInstaller.ps1`: https://gist.github.com/JrtPec/c59547a5b435924278d570a8f7ff2ca9. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that you need to have the full path for the `site-packages` folder.

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "site-packages"))
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(15).reshape(3, 5)

print "%r" % a
```

also since numpy contains some C++ dlls, make sure you copied it from a Windows machine.

Comment: It works! I found that using the site-packages from a 64bit Windows machine don't work, even though I had Azure set on 64bit. So I had to install a 32bit python3.4 environment on a Windows machine to grab the files from.