# "No space left on device" when installing Numpy on an Azure Web Role

Tags: python, azure, numpy, pip, azure-web-roles

I want to use Numpy and Pandas in a Python Web Role on Microsoft Azure.

I tried adding `numpy` and `pandas` to the `requirements.txt`, but this didn't work (using pip to install numpy often leads to problems so this was expected).

[I followed this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23831479/use-numpy-scipy-in-azure-web-role) and downloaded numpy as a wheel from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ and put the file in the root of the web role. Right now the `requirements.txt` looks like this:

```
azure>=0.8.0
azure-storage-logging
requests_futures
numpy-1.9.3+mkl-cp34-none-win32.whl
pandas
```

I remoted into the virtual machine and found some logs in `C:\Resources\Directory\7044b9f2b424470aa191d9c178d06399.WorkerRole1.DiagnosticStore\LogFiles\ConfigureCloudService`:

```
Storing debug log for failure in D:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\pip\pip.log
pip 1.5.6 from D:\Python34\lib\site-packages (python 3.4)
Unpacking e:\approot\numpy-1.9.3+mkl-cp34-none-win32.whl
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "D:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "D:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1197, in prepare_files
    do_download,
  File "D:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1364, in unpack_url
    unpack_file_url(link, location, download_dir)
  File "D:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 640, in unpack_file_url
    unpack_file(from_path, location, content_type, link)
  File "D:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\util.py", line 621, in unpack_file
    unzip_file(filename, location, flatten=not filename.endswith(('.pybundle', '.whl')))
  File "D:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\util.py", line 510, in unzip_file
    fp.write(data)
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

Storing debug log for failure in D:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\pip\pip.log
```

How can I get Numpy working?

Comment: your `D:` drive is out of space

Comment: Obviously, but this is a virtual machine managed by Microsoft Azure. I've tried upgrading my plan from extra-small to medium, but this seems to only increase memory size, not disk size.

Comment: you'll have to free some space then. Try removing some temporary directory

Comment: How could it be out of space? I haven't been able to execute any code yet, the only thing I have done was upload my package, which consists of some python code and the numpy wheel. Windows Explorer tells me the `D:` drive has 21.3 of 31.9 GB available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According your description, it looks like you host your python application on Azure Could Service. If you use Visual Studio as your IDE, I suggest that you can follow this solution:

You can try to set python virtual environment as python runtime in Web Role package, and leverage Visual Studio we can configure and deploy cloud service in python with a ease.

1, In your Azure Cloud Service project solution, right click **Python Environment** under your web role package, click **add virtual environment**.
[image]

2, If you named the virtual env as `env`, VS will create a VE folder named `env` in your web role root directory. Copy the wheel file `numpy-1.9.3+mkl-cp34-none-win32.whl` into `env` folder.

3, configure `requirements.txt`, to completely configure the dependencies of `pandas` and `numpy`, here is my `requirements.txt` looks like beside azure package:

```
pandas
numpy-1.9.3+mkl-cp34-none-win32.whl
six
pytz
```

4, right click the virtual env in the solution tree, click **Install from requirements.txt** to install all the packages.

[image]

5, then deploy it to Azure

It works fine via this method on my side. Any concern, please feel free let me know.

Comment: This works!
I had some issues with setting the Interpreter Path though. When building the project, a file called `AzureSetup.cfg` is generated which had the variable `interpreter_path` set to `%INTERPRETERPATH%`. I found no way to set this variable, or make it something like `%ROOTDIR%\env\Scripts\python.exe`.
What I finally did was editing `LaunchWorker.ps1`, changing the line `$interpreter_path = read_value 'interpreter_path'` to `$interpreter_path = $($Env:RootDir) + '\env\Scripts\python.exe'`

Comment: I have an update: pypi now includes wheels for windows, so you can just write `numpy` in `requirements.txt` and it will work, given that you update pip before it does the install. You can do this by adding a line to `ConfigureCloudService.ps1`: write `py -m pip install -U pip` right before it does `py -m pip install -r requirements.txt`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was caused by Drive C: is too full. All the temporary file for all of the process in your PC is stored in Drive C:, so you can't install big package when it's full.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working through this for about 3 days and after debugging the pip code and other bits and pieces my fix is:

iex "$env:PYPATH\Scripts\pip.exe install -b e:\approot\stuff -r requirements.txt"

notice the -b.

for some reason Windows/Python thought it had run out of room in the standard temp directory: c:\resources\app_id..... (when there was > 200GB full)

by using the -b it forces pip to use your own Build directory which doesn't fill up.

## sohappy

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with installing Numpy.

The base template for my Azure Web role I took from this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-python-ptvs).
As an idea to fix this error I took from [Gordon's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130951/no-space-left-on-device-when-installing-numpy-on-an-azure-web-role/41955720#41955720) answer.

I added tmp Local Storage to my RoleProperties:

[image]

After that made a change to the Startup task in the ServiceDefinition.csdef. Added a variable for the "tempdir":

```
<Task executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple" commandLine="bin\ps.cmd 
PipInstaller.ps1">
    <Environment>
      <Variable name="EMULATED">
        <RoleInstanceValue xpath="/RoleEnvironment/Deployment/@emulated" />
      </Variable>
      <Variable name="TEMPDIR">
        <RoleInstanceValue xpath="/RoleEnvironment/CurrentInstance/LocalResources/LocalResource[@name='tempdir']/@path" />
      </Variable>
      <Variable name="PYTHON2" value="off" />
    </Environment>
  </Task>
```

The final step. Changed "PipInstaller.ps1" to force pip to use "tempdir" as a Build directory:

```
$tmp_dir = $env:TEMPDIR
py -m pip install -b $tmp_dir -r ..\requirements.txt
```

Comment: At lot has changed since I first asked this question. Pip now has pre-built wheels for both Numpy and Pandas on Windows, so you don't need to include them yourself, or use a virtualenv.