# Azure Bottle web app and numpy

Tags: python, azure, numpy, azure-web-app-service, bottle

after publishing Bottle web app where I use NumPy library it says

> The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.

in local host it works. I used virtual environment as described in

> [Use numpy & scipy in Azure web role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23831479/use-numpy-scipy-in-azure-web-role)

but still does not work. Can someone help me with azure-python-numpy configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Mr.Green, Per my experience, first, my suggestion is that you can refer to the tutorial [Creating web apps with Bottle in Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-python-create-deploy-bottle-app/) to be sure your webapp with Bottle has been deployed correctly on Azure.

Second, you can install Python Tools for Visual Studio to remote debugging on Azure if you are using Visual Studio, please see the wiki page https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/wiki/Azure-Remote-Debugging to know how to debug.

Final, it's the most important. According to the [troubleshooting](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-python-create-deploy-bottle-app/#troubleshooting---package-installation) of the tutorial, you need to download the `numpy` wheel package from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy and install it for your python webapp to enable `numpy` runs on Azure. Because some packages like `numpy` installed using `pip` which required complier that is not available on the machine running the web app in Azure App Service, only installation of wheel packages.

Note: If the webapp still not works, please check the `numpy` package whether be appended into the python system path, and try to add the code below to solve it.

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "<numpy-package-path, such as 'site-package'>"))
```