# How to install scipy in Azure functions?

Tags: python, scipy, azure-functions, lapack, blas

If I create an Azure function with python 3.5.4 and type in the console

```
$ D:\home\site\tools\python.exe -m pip install scipy
```

I'm told that lapack/blas is missing.

```
  File "scipy\linalg\setup.py", line 20, in configuration
    raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found
```

How to install scipy in Azure function?

Comment: Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23831479/use-numpy-scipy-in-azure-web-role ? For Windows, I don't know the current state of the art with respect to NumPy/SciPy but installing from Gohlke's repositories is well established. The other post is for Python 2.7 but you should be able to adapt it easily.

Comment: I missed this topic, my bad. I've successfully been able to install scipy using the instructions in the link you provided.